# Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server enabled with Azure AD - How to give application access after restarts

Tags: postgresql, azure

I've setup an Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server and enabled ONLY Azure AD authentication, which [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-configure-sign-in-azure-ad-authentication#connect-to-azure-database-for-postgresql-by-using-azure-ad) supports token-based auth.

I can login using a service principal assigned to the Server AD users with the access-token method:

```
az login --service-principal -u "ID" -p "SECRET" --tenant "TENANT"
export PGPASSWORD=$(az account get-access-token --resource-type oss-rdbms --query "[accessToken]" -o tsv)
psql "host=mydatabase.database.azure.com user=service-principal dbname=db sslmode=require"
```

Question is, after I configure my application with the PostgreSQL environment variables:

```
pg_host='mydatabase.database.azure.com'
pg_port='5432'
pg_database='access-token'
pg_username='service-principal'
pg_password='<password>'
pg_sslmode='require'
```

The access-token's expire every 60min, it will only be valid for this session. If the VM restarts the app won't connect to the DB. I will have to log back in and change the `pg_password` to the new token.

How can we get around this with Flexible Server and AzureAD logins? I could setup a cron that changes the variable every time the VM reboots, but surely there must be another way with AzureAD logins?

Answer (score 0):

I created Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server and enabled Azure AD authentication like below:

[image]

I generated the Azure AD access token and verify through the API that access-tokens expire every 60 minutes like below:

[image]

To Increase the life time of access token, you can make use of below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId 6c3f1c39-b84c-XXXXXX -Scopes "Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework"

$params = @{  
Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"23:59:59"}}')  
DisplayName = "TokenLifeTime"  
IsOrganizationDefault = $true  
}  
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id
```

[image]

When I check the same in API the access token's validity life time is increased to 24hrs like below:

[image]

Now, When I try to connect server with DBeaver after restarting my vm its connecting successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

[Azure-docs/how-to-connect-with-managed-identity.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-connect-with-managed-identity.md)

Comment: Yea I've done that. 24hours still isn't very long. I think the best way is to refresh the token when the VM starts up, before postgresql can start and update the postgres config with the new token.